# Why I am I getting Null in my Mathematica function?

Tags: function, loops, null, wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I have made a function with mathematica and Im getting what I want from it however I am also getting 'Null' on the end and im not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
x = ""
ButterflyString[y_]:=For[i = 1, i < 8, i++, x = StringTake[y, {i}] <> x] x
```

My input:

```
ButterflyString["Wolfram"]
```

My output:

```
marfloW Null
```

Comment: @Bill That worked, thanks. I have looked at the code and I can see where I went wrong. Since i come from Python I was struggling with the syntax of functions and how I could add another line etc. I reccomend you post that as an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bill posted in the comments:

```
x = "";
ButterflyString[y_] :=
 (For[i = 1, i < 8, i++, x = StringTake[y, {i}] <> x];
  x)
```

This worked for me.